# how to make selected item from select box in my form to access a specific row in database and display that row in div tag anytime i change item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have a select box in my HTML that contain some items,
    anytime i select an item i need that item to query the database table   row and display that database table field in a div tag element or  a textarea element.

```
<select class="form-control" name="pd"  required="required" id="pd">
  <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Biology Chemistry Physics [BCP]">BCP</option>
  <option value="Chemistry Mathematics Physics [CMP]">CMP</option>
  <option value="Geography Mathematics Physics [GMP]">GMP</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you will need a js event listener to trigger an [ajax call](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp), when the select box is changed:

```
//  Attach event listeners when document is loaded (DOM tree is ready)
$(document).ready(function() {
    //  Trigger ajax call when select#pd is changed
    //  if you use jquery version lower than 1.7
    //  use $('#pd').live('change', function() {});
    $('#pd').on('change', function() {
        //  The data to send though the ajax call
        //  if it's not the value of the select what you need
        //  to query your database, change it
        var postData = {
            'id': $(this).val(),

        };

        //  test.php is the target of the ajax call
        //  if you have your php code in an other file,
        //  change it
        $.post( 'test.php', postData, function(data, status) {
            //  $('#div_container') is where you want to display
            //  the result of your ajax call
            $('#div_container').html(data);

        });

    });

});
```

In the `test.php` file you need to query the database, create the result you want to display in the div container mentioned above:

```
<?php
    //  Connect to the database, if needed
    $host   = 'localhost';
    $user   = 'username';
    $pass   = 'password';
    $db     = 'database_name';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    // check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    //  Data provided by the ajax call
    $id = $mysqli->escape_string( $_POST['id'] );

    //  Query your data from database
    //  Obviously, you have to write a query to aquire the desired data
    $query = "select * from table where column = '$id';";

    //  Create the required html structure from query data to return
    //  In this case, I want to create a table 
    //  containing 4 columns(Col0..Col3) of my result set
    ob_start();

    if( $result = $mysqli->query($query) ) {
        ?><table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col0</th>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody><?php
                while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    ?><tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Col0']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Col1']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Col2']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['Col3']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php

                }
            ?></tbody>
        </table><?php

        //  Free result set
        $result->free();

    }
    else {
        //  Handle failed query
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        exit();

    }

    //  Close connection if needed
    $mysqli->close();

    //  Gather the data from ob
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    //  Return the html structure
    echo $html;
```

If you have any question about it, feel free to ask.